# My grey / white hairs disappeared - in some sense, is aging reversible?

Tags: hair, stress, aging, hair-color

I accumulated less than a handful of grey / white hairs during some stressful days in graduate school.  I looked in the mirror often and couldn't believe that I was "aging".

Now, having finished with school and living a happier, more productive and emotionally intelligent lifestyle, I notice that those white hairs on my head have disappeared.  I haven't made any drastic changes -- my hairstyle is still neither short nor long, I eat sort of poorly but drink a lot of cow milk and unsweetened green tea that's fortified with 200% vitamin C, and I sleep at least eight hours a day.

If grey / white hairs is a sign of stress and aging, does the disappearance of white hairs from my head indicate in some sense that aging is reversible -- primarily by reducing the stress in my life?

Thanks,

Comment: Since we do not know how much hair disappeared: possible that a few grey hairs where concerning when visible and those few now just fell out for good?

Comment: Dont think this qualifies as age reversal. You were under stress, your body responded. Now, since those triggers and are not there, your body is no reacting.